# Can extremely nested CSS slow down a web page?

Tags: css

I've a `table` on my web application's dashboard. Rows are added to it dynamically by one of the Backbone's view. Although addition of new element is fast, scrolling lags when the number of `<tr>`s exceed 100.

I had a `mouseout` event binding on each `<tr>` which I've got rid of now. This hasn't solved the problem though. I'm considering CSS to be the culprit now. I've nested styles defined for  `tbody:first-child`, `tr:first-child`, `td:last-child` for both, normal and `hover` state, along with general styling for `tbody`, `tr`, `td` and `tbody:hover`, `tr:hover`, `td:hover`.

Although I very much doubt this is the reason for the lag, I'm left with no other suspect. Is it possible that CSS is adding to the slow down?

CSS - https://gist.github.com/4138323

Comment: Did you try removing the CSS in question? Does it still lag?

Comment: I don't see any examples of "extreme nesting" here.  Certain styling effects can cause sluggish scrolling, though.  Opera chugs if you use extremely tiny repeating backgrounds (like 2x2 tiny).  I've heard box-shadow is particularly resource intensive.  Without code, we're just guessing.

Comment: I have seen reports of nested CSS causing lag in rendering only. Can we see your code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I've added the CSS here - https://gist.github.com/4138323. @thirtydot, I'll try redoing the styles and update later today.

Comment: That's not css.  It looks like it might be ["Sass CSS"](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: scrolling lag is often caused by having lots of large images in the page.  It's especially bad if the images themselves are large, but they're scaled down (eg. by setting width/height) to fit in the page. Show us more code, and we'll give you something other than guesses.

Comment: Yep. It's SCSS. But you can see the nesting.

Comment: @Lee - Most of the DOM is constructed by Backbone Views which will make a lot of code to paste in here. Although you can log in and check the application if you wish. 

[ url : http://rankdemon.com/ranks,

user : test@rankdemon.com,

pass : rankdemon]

Also, after sanitizing the CSS a little, the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the deeply nested CSS which was slowing it down it seems. This might be completely vague but I'll still post what worked for me.

My setup was adding 100 `<tr>`s and around 40 `<tbody>`s to a `<table>` which were then removed/re-rendered based on user activity. This didn't work in IE of course because IE doesn't allow addition of `<tr>`s after `DOM` has loaded. Hence I resorted to using `div`s and `span`s and surprisingly, this reduced the lag on other browsers. Everything's working smooth now.